# linear algebra norm from inner space

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

so we have a symmetric diagonal matrix W and I have proven that the following is an inner product
$$\langle x,y\rangle_W = x^TWy$$
now I am asked to prove that
$$\|x\| = \langle x, x \rangle$$ is a norm.
is there a mistake in the question? isn't the correct norm with a square root like this
$$\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle }$$
or I am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, $<x,x>$ is the square.

Comment: Symmetric and diagonal is not enough for $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_W$ to be an inner product

Comment: You are right. There is an error in what you are given. Even in 1 dimension, with $W=(1)$, and hence $<x,x>=x^2,$ we do not  have a Triangle Inequality $<x,x>+<y,y>\,\ge \,<x+y,x+y>$ for all real $x,y $.

Comment: @Meowdog  I should have wrote also that every element in matrix W is w>0. I think now we can say that our matrix is positive definite so it is an inner product. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lucian_x098 you are not wrong, this is exactly it

Answer (score 1):

The second one is, in general, the norm inducted by an inner product. But you can ask if the first is or no a norm. The second one is called so because if you have a norm for which is true the parallelogram's identity it's defined an inner product such that the $\sqrt{<.,.>}$ is the originary norm. (I didn't check ii the first is an inner product, if you had a general matrix or a specific one).

Answer (score 0):

For $x \neq 0$, $\langle x, x\rangle_W>0$. Take $x=\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
a
\end{pmatrix}$, $W=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & -a
\end{pmatrix}$ for $a\neq0$. Then calculate that $\langle x, x\rangle_W=x^TWx=0$ but $x\neq0$. That's not an inner product.

Comment: I should have wrote also that every element in matrix W is w>0. I think now we can say that our matrix is positive definite so it is an inner product. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes if $W>O$ (positive definite), you are right.  You are right about the norm too.

Comment: thank for your input. It was driving me nuts. I have one last question. If instead of w>0 we had w>=0 and therefore a positive semi definite matrix would that change anything? I think then we wouldn't have an inner product. Am I correct to assume that?

Comment: Yes, being semi-definite isn't enough. Take $x=(1 ~~~
0 )^T$, $w_{11}=w_{12}=w_{21}=0,~w_{22}=1$